# Regex for java.util.Scanner for csv files?

Tags: java, regex, csv

I want to read a CSV file using `java.util.Scanner`. First attempt looked promising:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(cFile);
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String curLine = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    this.processRow(curLine);
 }

 private void processRow(String workString) {
     Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(workString);
     lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
     // .next goes through the elements
     lineScanner.next();
 }
```

The challenge I'm facing is the line `lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");`. My CSV has commas inside the text and escaped double Quotes:

```
 Year,Value,Customer,NickName,Rank
 2012,45.56,T3456C,"Mike, \"The Gangster\"",1
 2012,1237.35,"A453F", Joe Armagendon,2
 2012,,X344,"Frank the weasel",3
```

Is there a regex that only filters the separators?

Comment: I think it is better if you use a parser for this purpose. The regex must be able to understand the escape rule to parse this.

Comment: That is not CSV. In CSV quotes would be escaped with quotes. See [RFC 4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Comment: @Joey: It is badly formed - I know, but that's the worst case files I get. I probably can armtwist them into at least put quotes around Strings

Comment: Well, quotes are only necessary if you need your delimiter (or quotes)  in fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by nhahtdh, you should actually use a parser, as the way CSV works is a bit more complicated than the example.

There are many libraries for this out there. One I've used and forked is [csvfile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvfile/). It's pretty easy to use and does the job right.

Comment: You are right about this. However, I have created a fork of csvfile and placed it under Github with improvements. One of them is support for line count. You can check the project here: https://github.com/carlspring/csv-db-tools . I am planning on making the project available via Maven Central.

Comment: Just a comment readed on the Source Forge site 'csvfile'. - Thanks for the new links.